# using CRM web service with HTML and javascript

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I found some sample code in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 SDK which is asking me to do the following to test the soap call

1. Paste the following code into any Event Detail Properties dialog
   box.
2. Save the form and then click Create Form on the Preview menu.

The web service can only be used after the user is authenticated. The SOAP request contains CrmAuthenticationToken which is to be passed in the header. Since it cannot be anonymous I think the service can only be consumed within "CRM"

Is it possible to consume CRM web services from a self hosted HTML file?

Comment: Only if the HTML page is uploaded as a *Webresource*

Comment: Thanks Anwar. Can you add your reply as an answer? I will accept it as an answer and this question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML pages can consume Web Services by uploading it as a Webresource.

This link talks about *Relative Paths* and Simulating *Directories* 
[CRM 2011 Web Resources: Simulating Directories and the Importance of Relative Paths](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lezamax/archive/2010/10/21/crm-2011-web-resources-simulating-directories-and-the-importance-of-relative-paths.aspx)

This link talks about using jQuery to consume Web services
[Using jQuery in CRM 2011](http://crmconsultancy.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/using-jquery-in-crm-2011/)